# How to do Spring Controller method specific serialization with Jackson?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

I have two different serializers for String fields. I want to use either of them conditionally based on  an annotation present on the calling Controller method. I'm looking at different ways of doing this via Jackson (eg. annotationIntrospector, JsonView etc). However, I do not see anywhere I can use method annotation during serialization. I can probably check if I can follow something similar to how Jackson implements JsonViews but haven't got to a solution yet.

Here is the use case.

```
// Dto
public class MyDto {
   @Masked //Mask the fields with an option to avoid masking based controller method annotation.
   private final String stringField;
   // getters, setters.
}


// controller.

// default behavior is to serialize masked.
@ResponseBody
public MyDto getMaskedDto() {
  // return dto with masked value.
  return this.someService.getDto();
}

// Controller
@IgnoreMasking  // Do not mask the dto if method is annotated with @IgnoreMasking.
@ResponseBody
public MyDto getDtoSkipMasking() {
  // return dto without masking String field value.
  return this.someService.getDto();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "masking". Replacing some strings with ' ****** ' characters?

Comment: yes. Doing something with the string during serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend Jackon's `StdSerializer` and override the `serialize` method.

So something like this:

1. Create a new `CustomSerializer` class extending `StdSerializer`
2. Override the `serialize` method
3. In the overridden method, check for the existence of the object being serialised for the existence of your custom annotation (ie `IgnoreMasking`). You can do this via reflection
4. Do your processing
5. Register your custom serializer into Jackson's ObjectMapper configuration as a new `SimpleModule`

Comment: I get that. However, I want to be able to pick this CustomSerializer only if controller method is not annotated with @IgnoreMasking. Basically being able to use specific serializer per controller method

Comment: Ah, I think I missed the fact that you wanted that annotation on the Controller specifically. In that case, you could use Aspects to wrap around all controller calls and in this Aspect retrieve the controller handle, check for the existence of your `IgnoreMasking` annotation from the `ProceedingJoinPoint` and then mask your DTO accordingly.

Comment: Sure. That'll be going away from Jackson serialization then. I'll have to modify the objects in stead of just serializing them differently which is what I was hoping to avoid.